# How to Handle Backpressure in RxJava when Combining Observables with Different Emission Rates?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where I need to combine multiple Observables using RxJava, but these Observables have different emission rates. I'm running into issues with backpressure, and I'm not sure how to handle it effectively.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Observable<Integer> source1 = // some observable with fast emission rate
Observable<String> source2 = // another observable with a slower emission rate

Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2, (num, str) -> "Result: " + num + str)
        .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

The issue I'm facing is that the faster-emitting observable (source1) causes backpressure when combined with the slower one (source2). I've looked into strategies like using onBackpressureLatest or onBackpressureBuffer, but I'm not sure which one is more suitable for my case, and if there are any best practices for handling such scenarios.

Can someone provide guidance on the best approach to handle backpressure in this context? Any code examples or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exact problem do you have with backpressure in combining these two observables? You should get a pair of values as soon as both observables have generated values. When you have a fast-emitting source you will get pairs with different values from the fast-emitting source but with the same slow-emitting value. Or are you talking about the very first pair, which isn't produced because the slow-emitting observable hasn't generated any value yet? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have (maybe even add a marble diagram).